# How to create variables using a php array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array, something like below:

```
Array(

  [0] => Array
      (
          [name] => month_year
          [value] => 201609
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [name] => advance_amount
          [value] => 50%
      )

)
```

Using this array, I want to create 2 variables like this:

```
$month_year = '201609'; 
$advance_amount = '50%';
```

Can anybody tell me is this possible in php?

I tried it using two `foreach` but I don't have any idea how to precced.

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $data) {
  //echo "<pre>", print_r($data)."</pre>";
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."<br>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Your `foreach` loop should be like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $data) {
    $$data['name'] = $data['value'];
}

// display variables
echo $month_year . "<br />";
echo $advance_amount;
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP7 style:

```
$a = [['name' = 'month_year', 'value' => '201609'], ['name' => 'advance_amount', 'value' => '50%']];


foreach ($a as $line) {
    ${$line['name']} = $line['value'];
}

php > echo $month_year; //201609
```

Have a look at the [Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) reference

> Caution
>
> Further dereferencing a variable property that is an array has
>   different semantics between PHP 5 and PHP 7. The PHP 7.0 migration
>   guide includes further details on the types of expressions that have
>   changed, and how to place curly braces to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

using list it gives you the cleaner way to solve the issue: for example

```
$data = [
    [
        'name' => 'month_year',
        'value' => 201609
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'advance_amount',
        'value' => '50%'
    ]
];

list($month_year, $advance_amount) = array_map(function($value){
    return $value['value'];
}, $data);

echo sprintf('Month of the year is %s with porcentage %s', $month_year, $advance_amount);
```

This will have the result you are looking for with a clearer code.

```
Month of the year is 201609 with porcentage 50%
```

Answer (score 0):

first create loop and declare var.

```
  $data = array(array(
            'name' => 'month_year',
            'value' => 201609,
        ), array(
            'name' => 'advance_amount',
            'value' => '50%',
        )
    );

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        ${$value['name']} = $value['value'];
    }


    echo $month_year;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $advance_amount;
```